# CodeIgniter - dropdown menu passing position in list to db rather than value

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdown

I'm writing a small app using Codeigniter and run into a few issues so far! I have a drop down list that is populated from a db table. The drop down is populated and displays correctly however when I try to save its contents (values) to a new db table, it is saving the position in the dropdown list, rather than the value that is displayed.

Part of the form in View:

```
    <?php echo form_open('manage/create_sold_vehicle_record'); ?>
    Registration Number
    <br>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('reg_no', $vehicle_list, 'large'); ?>
```

The relevant part of the controller:

```
    function sell_vehicle()
    {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('MVehicle','',TRUE);
    $this->load->model('manage_model','',TRUE);
    $vehicles_qry = $this->MVehicle->listSaleVehicles();

    $vehicle_list = array();
    foreach ($vehicles_qry->result() as $vehicle)
    {
        $vehicle_list[] = $vehicle->reg_no;
    }

    $data['vehicle_list'] = $vehicle_list;
    $data['main_content'] = 'sell_stock_vehicle';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
    }
```

This is the Model:

```
    function create_sold_vehicle_record()
    {


        $new_vehicle_insert_data = array(
            'reg_no' => $this->input->post('reg_no'), <-- This is saved to db, but is the position in dropdown list, not the value shown.
            'sold_by' => $this->input->post('staff'),
            'bought_by' => $this->input->post('customer'),
            'sale_price' => $this->input->post('sale_price'),
            'comm_rate' => $this->input->post('comm_rate'),
            'total_comm' => $this->input->post('total_comm'),
            'sale_date' => $this->input->post('date')
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('sold_vehicles', $new_vehicle_insert_data);

        return $insert;
    }
```

So, rather than for example save 'OU03XHC' as the reg_no value in db, it is saving '1' (or whatever the position of the value was in the drop down list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$vehicle_list[]` needs to be an associative array

```
$vehicle_list = array();
foreach ($vehicles_qry->result() as $vehicle)
{
    $vehicle_list[$vehicle->reg_no] = $vehicle->reg_no;
}
```

Now form_dropdown() produces also option values (other than 0,1,etc.) in the dropdown html

Comment: Hi there - thanks for that, it worked perfectly for reg_no field!

Comment: Unfortunately I have 2 others, staff and customer and doing the same does not seem to work on these...  <pre>$staff_qry = $this->manage_model->listStaff();

  $staff_list = array();
  foreach ($staff_qry->result() as $staff)
  {
   $staff_list[$staff->lname] = $staff->lname;
  }</pre>  Any ideas why that would be? Thanks.

Comment: check the html created by form_dropdown() for staff and customer, what is 'value' ?

Comment: The dropdown list correctly displays the db table contents (is that what you mean? - sorry) - the value that is being written to the new table is just 0 (zero) for staff and customer. Thx.

Comment: pls check your 2nd dropdown, it should be something like :<?php echo form_dropdown('lname', $staff_list); ?>

Comment: Yup - that's exactly what I got.. <?php echo form_dropdown('lname', $staff_list, 'large'); ?>

Comment: Fixed it - dumb error. Type in db was set to int for customer & staff. Doh (throwback from old version) Sorted & working fine now. Thanks loads.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$vehicle_list = array();
 foreach ($vehicles_qry->result() as $vehicle)
 {
   $vehicle_list[] = $vehicle->reg_no;
 }
```

TO

```
$vehicle_list = array();
  foreach ($vehicles_qry->result() as $vehicle)
  {
      $vehicle_list[$vehicle->reg_value] = $vehicle->reg_no;
  }
```

"$vehicle->reg_value" veriable is value that you want to store in your DB